# How to use floating point tolerances in the Catch framework?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, catch-unit-test

I'm using the [Catch](http://github.com/philsquared/Catch) test framework.

In the [introductory blog post](http://www.levelofindirection.com/journal/2010/12/28/unit-testing-in-c-and-objective-c-just-got-easier.html) the author mentions the following feature:

> - Floating point tolerances supported in an easy to use way

I couldn't find any documentation on how to do this. How is this done in Catch?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's simple. There is a class called [`Approx`](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch/blob/master/docs/assertions.md#floating-point-comparisons) that lets you do this test in a very readable manner:

```cpp
#include <limits>
TEST_CASE("demo/approx", "Approx demo") {
    double a = 1.0;
    double b = a + std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon();
    REQUIRE_FALSE(b == a);
    REQUIRE(b == Approx(a));
}
```

The tolerance can be changed by using the member functions `epsilon()` and `scale()` of the `Approx` object, like so: `Approx(a).epsilon(e)`.

Comment: If you are going to down-vote explain why. To me this looks fine.

Comment: Related meta discussion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98766/is-it-ok-to-post-a-question-and-self-answer-it-within-1-minute

Comment: @Martin that was the sort of thing one would write in a comment, not in an edit.

Comment: @Martin no problem; you made me aware of the other answer which I had missed. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

The tolerance is has been customizable [since Apr 2011](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch/commit/dfea75fc05432e4704c9de4f7058b594db14a6dd). `Approx` has two member functions for this: `epsilon()` and `scale()`. For example:

```
REQUIRE(a == Approx(b).epsilon(my_eps));
```

The tolerance is ε × (*scale*+max(|*a*|, |*b*|)), where scale defaults to 1, so this will pass:

```
REQUIRE((2+2) == Approx(5).epsilon(0.17));
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I just stumbled upon the same problem and found a simple solution. In the Catch.hpp header file where the Approx class is defined (line 2045 at the time of writing), just add the following constructor:

```
class Approx {
public:
    explicit Approx( double value )
    :   m_epsilon( std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon()*100 ),
        m_scale( 1.0 ),
        m_value( value )
    {}

    explicit Approx( double value, double epsilon ) // <- New constructor
    :   m_epsilon( epsilon ),
        m_scale( 1.0 ),
        m_value( value )
    {}
```

Now you can do this:

```
TEST_CASE("demo/approx", "Approx demo") {
    double myTol = 0.1;
    double a = 1.0;
    double b = a + myTol;
    REQUIRE_FALSE(a == b);
    REQUIRE(a == Approx(b, myTol)); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is important to note that `Approx` is now considered deprecated [[source]](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/comparing-floating-point-numbers.md#top):

> The downside to Approx is that it has a couple of issues that we
> cannot fix without breaking backwards compatibility. Because Catch2
> also provides complete set of matchers that implement different
> floating point comparison methods, Approx is left as-is, is considered
> deprecated, and should not be used in new code.

As of version 2.10, one should switch to [using `Matchers`](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/comparing-floating-point-numbers.md#top).

```
    #include <limits>
    #include <catch2/matchers/catch_matchers_floating_point.hpp>

    TEST_CASE("demo/matchers", "Matchers demo") {
        double a = 1.0;
        double b = a + std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon();
        REQUIRE_FALSE(b == a);
        REQUIRE_THAT(b, Catch::Matchers::WithinRel(a, std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()));
    }
```