# How to compare floating point in catch2

Tags: c++, catch-unit-test, catch2

I am using Catch v2.13.1

What is the correct way to compare float values. I thought the below would fail, but both pass.

```cpp
REQUIRE(1147332687.7189338 == Approx(1147332688.4281545).margin(0.0001));
REQUIRE(1147332687.7189338 == Approx(1147332688.4281545));
```

However this fails as expected

```cpp
REQUIRE(abs(1147332687.7189338 - 1147332688.4281545) <= Approx(0).margin(0.0001));
```

I don't understand why the first two statements wouldn't work

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6718343/2410359) and [that](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/master/docs/assertions.md) may be useful.

Comment: Sadly can't run [your example on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/473b6E) and it should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of things to consider in the posted example.

```cpp
REQUIRE(1147332687.7189338 == Approx(1147332688.4281545));
```

This will pass, "unexpectedly". The reason can be found in the documentation ([assertions - floating point comparisons](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/master/docs/assertions.md#floating-point-comparisons)).

> `Approx` is constructed with defaults that should cover most simple cases. For the more complex cases, Approx provides 3 customization points:
>
> - **epsilon** - epsilon serves to set the coefficient by which a result can differ from `Approx`'s value before it is rejected. By default set to `std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon()*100`.
> - [...]

In the posted example, the two numbers differ by a cofficient near 6.2e-10, while the default is (given a 32-bit float) near 1.2e-5.

The following test wouldn't pass.

```cpp
CHECK( a == Approx(b).epsilon(1e-12) );
```

---

The other tests involve `margin`, which is described in the documentation as

> - **margin** - margin serves to set the the absolute value by which a result can differ from Approx's value before it is rejected. By default set to 0.0.

The caveat, though, can be found in [issue#1507](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/issues/1507).

> This is because of the default value for epsilon in the Approx class and the fact that Approx::equalityComparisonImpl will pass if the value is in the range of the margin **OR** the epsilon values.

So, this test wouldn't pass:

```cpp
CHECK( a == Approx(b).margin(0.0001).epsilon(1e-12) );
```

Note that this "issue" seems to be marked as [resolved](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/issues/1507#issuecomment-457859511) - not a bug:

> So, I don't think this is a bug.
>
> The reason for this is that it is very hard (well, impossible), to determine the user's intent, thus it is better to assume that the user has set up both checks correctly -- after all, if the user does not want a relative comparison, they can always set the epsilon to zero. In fact, I think that using both tolerances and taking the most forgiving one is the superior option to implement things like the Approx Matcher ([#1499](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/pull/1499)).

Comment: Thank you, I don't understand why margin exists if it has incorrect behavior depending on what epsilon is set to.

Comment: @Inquisitor Yeah, that's a debatable design choice, IMHO. Robust floating point comparison is kind of an esoteric art, though, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595425/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-floats-for-almost-equality-in-python and the link there.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using a Catch version >= 2.10, you might want to switch to `Matchers` which is the recommended way of dealing with floating point comparison in Catch ([the doc](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/comparing-floating-point-numbers.md#top) advises against using `Approx` in new code).
They make for a much improved, foolproof test API.

> The downside to Approx is that it has a couple of issues that we cannot fix without breaking backwards compatibility. Because Catch2 also provides complete set of matchers that implement different floating point comparison methods, Approx is left as-is, is considered deprecated, and should not be used in new code.

```
#include <catch2/matchers/catch_matchers_floating_point.hpp>
REQUIRE_THAT(1147332687.7189338, Catch::Matchers::WithinAbs(1147332688.4281545, 0.0001)); // fails
```